# Access denied for pdf to read using itextsharp at server level

Tags: c#

Am facing error after uploadind to server... as access denied .... can anyone help me....

```
  Document myDocument = new Document(PageSize.A5, 26, 72, 180, 180);
  string strUniqueFn = "onlineinvoice.pdf";
  string imgpath = "logo.gif";    



  string strUser = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name.Substring(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1).ToUpper();
  string strFolder = Server.MapPath(".");
  System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(strFolder);
  System.IO.FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles(strUser + "*.*");

  for (i = 0; i <= fi.Length - 1; i++)
  {
      System.IO.File.Delete(strFolder + "\\" + strUniqueFn);
  }

  string strPath = strFolder + "\\" + strUniqueFn;

  PdfWriter pdfw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(myDocument, new FileStream(strPath, FileMode.Create));
  string iPath = strFolder + "\\" + imgpath;
  pdfw.CloseStream = false;

  myDocument.Open();

  ......................

  myDocument.Close();
```

Am facing error at `PdfWriter pdfw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(myDocument, new FileStream(strPath, FileMode.Create));`

can anyone help me...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is just a bug on your GetFiles / delete routine ("onlineinvoice.pdf" probably doesn't have strUser at the beginning ... ):

```
System.IO.FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles(strUser + "*.*");
    for (i = 0; i <= fi.Length - 1; i++)
    {

        System.IO.File.Delete(strFolder + "\\" + strUniqueFn);
    }
```

**Update 1:** Don't put the files at the root level of your site, have them grouped on a folder where you can give specific write/delete permissions.

Comment: hey it never work even if u remove delete function and even if you add folder

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to create a file in the root folder of your site. When doing so you get an access denied exception. The following instruction: `new FileStream(strPath, FileMode.Create)` will attempt to create a new file in the root folder of your site.
The exception is due to the fact that the account your site is running under doesn't have enough permissions to write to that directory. Either grant the account write permissions to the root folder or as Freddy Rios suggested create a subfolder to store your pdf files into and you will need to grant write permissions only to this subfolder.